# Displaying an image from a URL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I've got the URL of an image (http://www.example.com/logo.png), but I don't know how to use that to display the image.

I'm "pushing" the URL from my table view controller to a detail controller with a variable called `selectedImage`

I guess it should be something like this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 104)];
[imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"%@", selectedImage]]];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
```

but that doesn't display the image.

Comment: FYI, To _Parse_ is to "Analyse into its component parts and describe their syntactic roles." _Parsing an image_ would imply you're manually reading the image raw data or pixels to extract additional meaning from the image (i.e. in the way of Shape Recognition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to do this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/005/545/OpoQQ.jpg?1302279173"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
imageView.image = [[[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: Thanks but it's giving me an error; Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2

Comment: Thanks! No errors but the image is not displaying    `UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -10, 320, 104)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:selectedImage];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageView];`

Comment: Why are you sending it to the back? [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageView]; Dont do that

Comment: Because the image is 'overlaping' an other image needs to be on the background..and without that the code is not working..hmm

Comment: What exactly is selectedImage?

Comment: An url like http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/005/545/OpoQQ.jpg?1302279173

Comment: Ok, now I understand were the problem was, check my edit, you have the solution there

Comment: Oh the code is working with that url but i need to use 'selectedImage'

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the image as a `UIImage` you can just set it as the image view's `image` property.

```
imageView.image = yourImage;
```

No need for a background color.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, it is a remote file with a URL to an image? UIImage imageNamed won't work then.

Use

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: ....]
```

if file is on phone, or imageWithData and dataWithContentsOfURL (or even better asynchronous download)

cheers